# Viewing Eclipse's source code - how would we critique the algorithms?

Tags: java, eclipse

For a school project, we're to take Eclipse and critique its algorithms. I know Eclipse is open source, but how exactly do we navigate through the mess of folders and actually see some code that would be able to be critiqued?

Comment: which algorithms you want to critisize? The one of your school colleagues, or the source code of the eclispe developpment environment?

Comment: Ask your teacher / project supervisor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technics below help to spot code with poor design.
If you realy meant algorithms, instead of design, then eclipse will not help you much,
it then is only a text viewer, project browser. 
You are left alone with your "natural" intelligence.

**How to spot hints for poor design**
In Eclipse, open the project to be reviewed:
Install *FindBugs*, *PMD* amd *Checkstyle*

Critical:
findBugs Prio1 and 2
PMD 1  - 3?

Further Install "*Metrics*": (I forgot the exact name)

Look at high "cyclomatic complexity", to spot critical code.
In Checkstyle you would find that measure, too

Comment: FindBugs finds bugs and dodgy coding practices, not poorly chosen algorithms.

Comment: You are correct, but i doubt that in school they are able to distinguish between poorly (or not) choosen algorithms. Leave that to computer science experts with > 5 year of full time professional experience; What will they expect to find?  Some obvious known bad algorithms like "bubbleSort" or "recursive factorielle"? I doubt.